# Koala - user_photos permission not asked for when authentication with facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rubygems, koala

I have an application which authenticates users with Facebook using omniauth. I am getting all the data I need for this including the access token. I am using the Koala gem to communicate with Facebooks graph API which is working fine. So I have the following:

```
models/authentication.rb
def facebook
 @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
end
```

So using the usual koala commands works fine:

```
facebook.get_object("me") etc etc
```

I now want to pull in the users photos using something like:

```
facebook.get_object("me/photos")
```

This just returns an empty array. So I have looked into it and realised that I need to set the permission on Facebook developers site under permissions/User & Friend Permissions. This however doesn't seem to have any affect as when I run:

```
facebook.get_connections("me", "permissions")
```

I don't see the the user_photos permission in the returned array.

This is what I think is causing the issue, but not sure why it's not coming through.

Please let me know if there is any other information I could provide.
Any help will be much appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should request proper permission when you are get oauth token from the facebook for your application, for example it is OmniAuth used code that sets the `read_stream`, and `user_photos` permissions to a request for a user. The file is `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :facebook, :setup => true, :scope => 'read_stream, user_photos'
end
```

Comment: That did the trick, should have thought of it. Many thanks. I'll vote ur answer up as soon as I have enough rep points to do so.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ : We should also mention FB app_id and secret_key, after provider :facebook and before :scope, right? i.e it should be `provider :facebook, ENV['FB_APP_ID'], ENV['FB_SECRET_KEY'],{:scope => "user_photos"}`. Rails app still doesn't ask for user photos permission after logging in. Any settings to be made at facebook's developer site?

Comment: @rAzOr i believe you should make the keypair obsolete before requesting it again with new settings.